# Bash "if" statement throws "too many arguments"

Tags: bash, if-statement

This is the code that produces the error:

```
#!/bin/bash
types=([i]=Info [w]=Warning [e]=Error [se]=Severe)

function isValidType
{
    for type in "${!types[@]}"
    do
        if [ $1 == $type ]; then
            return 0
        fi
    done
    return 1
}

if [ isValidType "$msgType" -eq 1 ]; then # <---- error here
    echo "Invalid type."
    exit 0
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
if [ isValidType "$msgType" -eq 1 ]; then
```

to

```
isValidType "$msgType"
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
```

`[` is the `test` command which accepts an *expression* and doesn't work as you designed (Comparing the return value of the function).

Comment: If you want to test whether the command `isValidType "$msgType"` succeeded or not, there's no need to invoke `[`. Just invoke the command directly. See [rici's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19072567/827263).

Comment: OP wants to compare the value returned from the function which doesn't necessarily a success or failure (For example, *if returned value is 3 do something else*). If it's only a true boolean logic yes, `[` is needless. I personally prefer to use bash built-in `[[ .. ]]`.

Comment: The way the function is written, its result is clearly a success/failure indicator; `if isValidTYpe "$msgType"; then` would be better in this case than using `[`. An explicit test of `$?` would make sense for a function or command that returns more than two distinct results.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax of an `if` statement is:

```
if <list>; then <list>; [elif <list>; then <list>;]* [else <list>;]? fi
```

where `<list>` is any sequence of "pipelines" separated by `;`, `&&`, or `||`. (A pipeline is one or more simple commands separated by `|` symbols.)

The `if` statement is evaluated by first executing the `<list>` following the `if`, and checking the return code, which will be the return code of the last simple command executed. Based on that, a decision is made as to whether to execute the `<list>` following `then` (if the first list succeeeded) or to proceed with the `elif` tests and/or `else` clause.

Nowhere in that syntax does a `[` appear, and for a good reason. `[` is actually a command. In fact, it is *almost* a synonym for `test`; the difference is that `[` insists that its last argument be `]`.

It's sometimes convenient to use `[` (although it is almost always more convenient to use `[[`, but that's an essay for another day), but it is in no way obligatory. If you just want to test whether a command succeeded or not, then do so:

```
if isValidType "$msgType"; then
  # it's valid
else
  # it's not valid
fi
```

If you only need to do something if it didn't work, use the `!` special form:

```
if ! isValidType "$msgType"; then
  # it's not valid
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

To check if a function returns true or not the proper way to do this is:

```
if [ !isValidType ]; then
       // would throw a flag for any options passed that are invalid
       // error output
fi
```

This works if isValidType will be either one or zero.
I think the problem is in the you are checking the array.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Um, did you try that? `[` treats `isValidType` as a string, and tests whether it's non-empty; it doesn't even call the function. `!` inverts that result, so `[ ! isValidType ]` (add the space to avoid history substitution) is always false.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I got confused with $1 being for the script instead of the function.